# Two Way Binding with Mat-Error causes ngModelChange to fire excessively

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a mat input field in which I bind two-way data with ngModel, I would also like to incorporate mat-error with validation using a formControl.

```
<mat-form-field [formGroup]="myForm">
  <input matInput formControlName="myFormName" autocomplete="off" 
         (ngModelChange)="dataChanged(myValue)" [ngModel]="myValue">
  <mat-error>
    Error! Value outside <strong>{{minVal}}</strong>
    and <strong>{{maxVal}}</strong>.
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

However this gives me an issue where ngModelChange fires multiple times when the component is initialized and the ngModel value `myValue` is populated with data through HTTP calls in a service. Something about mixing template driven and reactive forms?

Essentially, what I am trying to achieve is two way bind data to an input while also having mat-errors without having ngModelChange fire unnecessarily just because I populate the input with data on init.

Comment: Why are you using `(ngModelChange)` and `[ngModel]` bindings in the first place if you have a reactive form in place?

Comment: @SiddAjmera Because I don't know how to achieve two way binding and form validation with only one or the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have a form that looks something like this:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import {
  FormGroup,
  FormControl,
  Validators
} from "@angular/forms";

/** @title Input with a custom ErrorStateMatcher */
@Component({
  selector: "input-error-state-matcher-example",
  templateUrl: "./input-error-state-matcher-example.html",
  styleUrls: ["./input-error-state-matcher-example.css"]
})
export class InputErrorStateMatcherExample {
  minVal = 8;
  maxVal = 20;

  myForm = new FormGroup({
    myFormName: new FormControl("", [
      Validators.minLength(this.minVal),
      Validators.maxLength(this.maxVal)
    ])
  });
}
```

Here, you've defined your `minLength` and `maxLength` validators.

You've also binded the form with your template using `[formGroup]` and `formControlName` directives.

So everything will be taken care of by Angular for you.

You just have to access the `errors` property on the `myForm.controls['myFormName']` control. Something like this:

```
<mat-form-field [formGroup]="myForm">
    <input matInput formControlName="myFormName" autocomplete="off">
    <mat-error *ngIf="myForm.controls['myFormName'].errors">
        Error! Value outside <strong>{{minVal}}</strong>
        and <strong>{{maxVal}}</strong>.
    </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-two-way-binding-in-angular-reactive-forms?file=src/app/input-error-state-matcher-example.html) for your ref.

Comment: This does not account for the fact that I Need to be able to populate the mat-form-field with data from an HTTP call on init.

Comment: Ofcourse it does. The first argument that we pass to the constructor function of a `FormControl` is the default value that it takes. I've just updated the Working Demo with a Network call that fetches a user and sets the name in the response as the default value for the field.

Comment: Once you get a hang of it, Angular Reactive Forms are really very powerful. I'd suggest you explore more on them. I have a [free video series about Reactive Forms](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLUcSYK_mU4eAfVRbJyHXRJKAzR666LTrc) that I recorded 2 years ago. You might want to check it out from Video 70. :)